# How do I assign a value to a corresponding header after extracting data from a DAT file (text file) using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 column of values in my DAT file, first being the time and the other being the voltage along with it. For example, 1 2 3 4 5 (time) and 18 20 22 25 26 (voltage) respectively.

The time is on the first column of the DAT file and the voltage is separated by a comma right beside it. I would like to attach the voltage values to the corresponding time values (18V to 1s, 20V to 2s etc).I have already managed to extract out the time and voltage but I do not know how to arrange the voltage to the corresponding time.

The reason why I need to do this is because there are many DAT files I need to extract the data from and not every one of the DAT files has the same time (some is 1 2 3 5 6 7). Hence my plan is to concatenate the time for all the DAT files (this part is done) and then attach their corresponding voltage to the time respectively according to their DAT file. Below is an example to illustrate my problem to make the question even clearer.

```html
DAT file(alpha)  
time voltage 
1, 18
2, 20
3, 22
4, 25
5, 26

DAT file(beta)
time voltage 
1, 180
2, 201
5, 222
6, 253
7, 265

DAT file(charlie)
time voltage 
1, 11
2, 23
6, 28
9, 22
10, 6
```

```html
To be printed on excel - 
time alpha beta charlie
1     18    180   11
2     20    201   23
3     22    0     0
4     25    0     0
5     26    222   0
6     0     253   28
7     0     265   0
9     0     0     22
10    0     0     6
```

Thank you!

Comment: Look for Power Query. Its perfect for Extracting, Transforming and Loading data

Comment: You assign first row as time no, for example row 3, then you assign each name as column order, for example alpha Col B, Beta Col C, Charlie Col D and Time Col A. Now you can put each data Alpha 1 18 for example, A3=1, B3=18, and other column let as is, then do loop to process all your data

Comment: but how do i do the loop if the time values are diff for each set of data? 

will take a look at power query too, thanks! @RicardoDiaz

Comment: Add a column to your lists and fill it with a `ListID`, like "A", "B" or "C", same ID for all items in a list. Merge all your lists into one by appending them. Sort the combined list on time. Then write a macro to sort duplicates into the format you want. You should be able to append another set of new data to an existing list produced by the above method.

Comment: Does this have to be done in excel? You might want to look for some Access or r solutions.

Comment: yes it has to be done on excel @jivko

Comment: is it possible to show me how the sorting code works? i'm not too sure how to do it. thank you @Variatus

Answer (score 0):

Ok maybe let me try another approach of asking the question - extraction and cleaning of data is not a problem, so i am able to get the following on excel as shown below (using the same example).

```html
1  18  1 180  1 11
2  20  2 201  2 23
3  22  5 222  6 28  
4  25  6 253  9 22
5  26  7 265  10 6
```

so now i need a code to sort these data such that i can get this -

```html
1     18    180   11
2     20    201   23
3     22    0     0
4     25    0     0
5     26    222   0
6     0     253   28
7     0     265   0
9     0     0     22
10    0     0     6
```

hope this is clearer and thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here as your sample:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a As Integer
    Dim Pos As Long
    Dim RowBegin As Long
    Dim myRange As Range
    For a = 1 To 3
        Pos = 2
        RowBegin = 2
        Do While True
           If a = 1 Then CelCol = "A"
           If a = 2 Then CelCol = "C"
           If a = 3 Then CelCol = "E"
           RsltCol = "H"
           If IsEmpty(Range("Sheet1!" & CelCol & Pos).Value) = True Then Exit Do
           Set myRange = Range("Sheet1!" & RsltCol & Range("Sheet1!" & CelCol & Pos).Value + RowBegin - 1)
           myRange.Offset(0, 0).Value = Range("Sheet1!" & CelCol & Pos).Value
           If IsEmpty(myRange.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then myRange.Offset(0, 1).Value = 0
           If IsEmpty(myRange.Offset(0, 2).Value) Then myRange.Offset(0, 2).Value = 0
           If IsEmpty(myRange.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then myRange.Offset(0, 3).Value = 0
           myRange.Offset(0, a).Value = Range("Sheet1!" & CelCol & Pos).Offset(0, 1).Value
           Pos = Pos + 1
        Loop
    Next
End Sub
```

The source and the result in sheet1 as pict:

[image]

Comment: What about with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an implementation of my suggestion. Please try it. Key is that the data are written to an output sheet, leaving the original intact. You can substitute input sheets and have them added to an existing output sheet. The resulting new output sheet will not have sorted rows and columns, however, because sorting is done prior to creating an original output sheet. Please try my code and see how you like it.

```
Option Explicit

Enum Nws                            ' Worksheet navigation
    NwsCapRow = 1
    NwsFirstDataRow                 ' no value assigned means previous + 1
    NwsBatch = 1                    ' 1 = column A
    NwsTime
    NwsVolt
    NwsTTime = 1                    ' Output sheet:
    Nws1stBatch = 5                 ' could be any column on the right
End Enum

Sub SortToColumns()
    ' Variatus @STO 31 Jan 2020

    Dim WsS As Worksheet            ' Source (input)
    Dim WsT As Worksheet            ' Target (output)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Fnd As Range
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim Rls As Long                 ' WsS.last row
    Dim Rs As Long, Rt As Long      ' Source / Target row
    Dim Cs As Long, Ct As Long      ' Source / Target column

    ' This worksheet has your DAT files, in Excel format, appended
    ' below each other (no headers, no blank rows)
    ' A column A was inserted in which a unique identifier
    ' for each DAT file is written.
    ' (all entries from one file have the same identifier)
    Set WsS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input")          ' change the Ws name to suit

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set WsT = .Item("Output")                       ' change to suit
        If Err Then
            Set WsT = .Add(After:=.Item(.Count))
            With WsT
                .Name = "Output"                        ' change to suit
                ' add captions & formatting here
            End With
        End If
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0
    With WsS
        Rls = .Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsBatch).End(xlUp).Row
        Cs = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsBatch), .Cells(Rls, Cs))
        With .Sort.SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Rng.Columns(NwsTime), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Rng.Columns(NwsBatch), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                 Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With .Sort
            .SetRange Rng
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False              ' change to suit
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

    With WsT
        For Rs = NwsFirstDataRow To Rls
            Ct = Application.Max(.Cells(NwsCapRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column, Nws1stBatch)
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsCapRow, Nws1stBatch), .Cells(NwsCapRow, Ct))
            Tmp = WsS.Cells(Rs, NwsBatch).Value
            Set Fnd = Rng.Find(Tmp, Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)
            If Fnd Is Nothing Then
                Ct = Rng.Column + IIf(Rng.Cells(1).Value = "", Rng.Cells.Count, 0)
                .Cells(NwsCapRow, Ct).Value = Tmp
            Else
                Ct = Fnd.Column
            End If

            Rt = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, NwsTTime).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 2)
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(NwsFirstDataRow, NwsTTime), .Cells(Rt, NwsTTime))
            Tmp = WsS.Cells(Rs, NwsTime).Value
            Set Fnd = Rng.Find(Tmp, Rng.Cells(Rng.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext)
            If Not Fnd Is Nothing Then Rt = Fnd.Row
            .Cells(Rt, NwsTTime).Value = WsS.Cells(Rs, NwsTime).Value
            .Cells(Rt, Ct).Value = WsS.Cells(Rs, NwsVolt).Value
        Next Rs
    End With
End Sub
```